# WooCommerce nonce validation issue

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, nonce

I am trying to update a custom plugin to work with the upcoming change in browsers where third party cookies will be blocked.

The plugin does an API integration, and it has been suggested that we fix this by using a reference ID in the URL. We have added a nonce and it works OK for registered users, but for unregistered users it works erratically. I believe the issue is related to:

- 5.9.9 - 12.05.2019

  - Fix: WooCommerce 3.6 change use Woo generated customer ID's for non-authenticated users to prevent broken security nonce cookies.

Apparently WooCommerce changes the session ID after the nonce is created which causes it to fail authentication. I read somewhere that I should create the WooCommerce session manually, but I am unsure how to go about that.